# How to find synchronous increases of multiple variables in a time window?

Tags: r, time, filter, subset

I have a very large dataframe with measurements taken from different subjects over continuous time. I need to filter out those measurements that **increase in synchrony over all subjects in a certain time window**.

Here's some mock data; `v1`and `v2` are the measurements taken for two subjects:

```
df <- data.frame(
  time = 1:30,
  v1 = c(4,4,4,4,4,   2,4,5,5,6,  
         6,6,6,6,6,   5,5,6,7,7,  
         7,6,5,6,4,   5,5,5,5,4),
  v2 = c(0.93,0.82,0.99,1.01,1.01,   1.01,1.01,1.56,1.80,1.99,  
         1.01,0.05,1.05,1.02,0.01,   1.11,1.11,1.40,1.42,1.45,  
         1.00,1.00,1.11,1.99,1.34,   2.45,3.00,3.67,3.67,3.88)
)
```

Let's assume a time window of 5 seconds. How can I detect those rows in `df` where, in a 5-second time window, the values both in `v1`and `v2` increase in synchrony? By "increase" I mean this:
no value in the 5-value sequence must be smaller than the sequence-first value and at least the sequence-last value must be larger than the sequence-first value. That is, `1,1,1,1,2` would count as an increase, whereas `1,0,1,2,3` would not. I'd also like to group each sychronous increase by some grouping label, e.g., `a`, `b`, etc. The desired output would be:

```
df1
   time v1   v2 group
6     6  2 1.01     a
7     7  4 1.01     a
8     8  5 1.56     a
9     9  5 1.80     a
10   10  6 1.99     a
16   16  5 1.11     b
17   17  5 1.11     b
18   18  6 1.40     b
19   19  7 1.42     b
20   20  7 1.45     b
25   25  4 1.34     c
26   26  5 2.45     c
27   27  5 3.00     c
28   28  5 3.67     c
29   29  5 3.67     c
```

How can this be done? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by increasing in synchrony? Do they have to increase by the same value or is it enugh that just both increase in a gien timeframe?

Comment: It's enough that they increase in the same time window

Comment: The increase is an increase over the 5-value sequence: no value in it must be smaller than the sequence-first value and at least the sequence-last value must be larger than the sequence-first value. That is, `1,1,1,1,2`would count as an increase, whereas `1,0,1,2,3`would not.

Comment: Shouldn't rows 25-29 selected as well?

Comment: @Ronak Oh yes, absolutely! Well spotted! Have edited the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach :

Keeping it flexible for any number of measurements (columns `v1`, `v2`... `vn`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

window_size <- 5

result1 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c(v1, v2), ~lead(.) - ., .names = '{col}_diff')) %>%
  mutate(result = {tmp <- select(., ends_with('diff')); 
                   rowSums(tmp >= 0) == length(tmp)},
         group = rleid(result)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(n() >= window_size - 1)

result1

# A tibble: 12 x 7
# Groups:   group [3]
#    time    v1    v2 v1_diff v2_diff result group
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>  <int>
# 1     6     2  1.01       2   0     TRUE       4
# 2     7     4  1.01       1   0.55  TRUE       4
# 3     8     5  1.56       0   0.24  TRUE       4
# 4     9     5  1.8        1   0.190 TRUE       4
# 5    16     5  1.11       0   0     TRUE       8
# 6    17     5  1.11       1   0.290 TRUE       8
# 7    18     6  1.4        1   0.02  TRUE       8
# 8    19     7  1.42       0   0.03  TRUE       8
# 9    25     4  1.34       1   1.11  TRUE      12
#10    26     5  2.45       0   0.550 TRUE      12
#11    27     5  3          0   0.67  TRUE      12
#12    28     5  3.67       0   0     TRUE      12
```

Notice that we have `window_size - 1` in `filter` which is required since we are subtracting the current row with `lead` row which comes out to be negative for the last row in each group. That is also the reason the last row is not included in the same group. If the time is continuous you can get the row which has next value of `time` from each group.

```
result2 <- df %>%
  filter(time %in% (result1 %>% slice(n()) %>% pull(time) + 1))
result2
#  time v1   v2
#1   10  6 1.99
#2   20  7 1.45
#3   29  5 3.67
```

and now `rbind` `result1` and `result2` keeping only relevant columns from `result1`.

Comment: Cool but `rbind`does not insert the fifth values in the right rows...

Comment: you can `arrange` thereafter by time

Comment: @Ronak Thanks a million--great job!

Answer (score 1):

Below methodology will divide the data in separate groups at every nth row.  So if you want to check for condition at 0-5, 6-10, 11-16, ... this will work

```
library(dplyr)

#storing the window size
n1 <- 5L

#code for result
df %>% group_by(dummy = (row_number()-1) %/% n1) %>%
  filter((last(v1) > first(v1) & 
                         v1 >= first(v1) &
                         last(v2) > first(v2) &
                         v2 >= first(v2))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(grp = letters[dense_rank(dummy)])

# A tibble: 10 x 5
    time    v1    v2 dummy grp  
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1     6     2  1.01     1 a    
 2     7     4  1.01     1 a    
 3     8     5  1.56     1 a    
 4     9     5  1.8      1 a    
 5    10     6  1.99     1 a    
 6    16     5  1.11     3 b    
 7    17     5  1.11     3 b    
 8    18     6  1.4      3 b    
 9    19     7  1.42     3 b    
10    20     7  1.45     3 b
```

Comment: I get this error: `Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `dummy`.
x object 'n1' not found
ℹ Input `dummy` is `(row_number() - 1)%/%n1`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: Yeah! I also noticed.  The code by Ronak is perfect as mine will start at every nth row and will not check for sequence for every next row.